# On button click - call Ajax function

Tags: ajax, function, button

I stuck. I try to make Ajax call from button click. Function is loading and responding HTML data. HTML data in format like "< div>...< /div >". When I open "http://domain.com/load_info.php?id=1" in browser, I get all HTML data. But when I try to load it by Ajax function, nothing is loading.

buttons

```
   <input type='button' onclick='getInfo(1);' value='Load Info' >
```

Ajax Function

```
  function getInfo(id_number){
        alert('function started with id =' + in_number); // this alert works fine
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            data: { 'id': id_number },
            url : "load_info.php",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(response) {
              alert('success');                    // this alert is not working
              $("#info").prepend(response);
            }
        });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this approach if you are using jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.get("load_info.php",
    {
        id: id_number
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this button is in google map infoWindow. And is generated "on the fly". I need to find solution by my example.